# Black the zonejs "listening" event list in polyfills.ts in Angular 8 not working

Tags: angular

I've been trying to figure out how to stop `mousemove` event firing change detection in Angular.
Some articles mentioned I can achieve this by adding a line in `polyfills.ts`:
`(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['mousemove'];`

I've tried it in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqzoa5) and it perfectly works.
BUT, the tricky part is that it doesn't not work at all if I create a Angular project in my local and do totally the same thing. It just keeps triggering change detection on mousemove event even though I add the line above in `polyfills.ts`.

What am I missing? Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: please provide a reproduce repo, so I can try to debug.

Comment: @jialipassion https://github.com/binDongKim/try-zonejs this is the repo

Comment: I see, it seems to be an issue of Angular CLI with the newest zone.js, I will fix it and update the solution here, for now you need to

1. update `polyfills.ts` 
```
import './zone-flag';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```
2. create a new file called `zone-flag.ts`
```
(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['mousemove'];
```
Thanks!

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you so much :D

Comment: @jialipassion One question: do I have to add `(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;` in `zone-flag.ts` too if I want to prevent zonejs from detecting requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: yes, please add all zone related flags in `zone-flag.ts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @jialipassion, managed to nail it.

1. Create a new file, `zone-flag.ts` at the same level with `polyfills.ts`
2. Add `(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['mousemove'];` in `zone-flag.ts`:

```js
// in zone-flag.ts
(window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['mousemove'];
```

3. Add `import './zone-flag'` in `polyfills.ts`:

```js
// in polyfills.ts
import './zone-flag';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Hope this help anyone who might navigate here.

Comment: What is unfortunate is that this simply disables the change detection in the heavy wrapper that is the zone.js monkey patcher, but it still causes huge performance issues since you're still 10 levels deep in the microTask dispatcher of zone.js. I wish we could just eliminate the patching of these events in totality, but it just doesn't seem to work.