# Angular 8: Disabling specific events from being checked on polyfills.ts isn't working

Tags: angular, zonejs

I'm developing an application in angular 8 that uses jsPlumbToolkit to display and edit flowcharts. However i was experiencing performance issues, so i started digging and eventually realized that the change detection from zone.js was running at every mouse move event. So i tried adding the following line to pollyfills.ts, [as shown in this article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/beware-angular-can-steal-your-time-41fe589483df).

```
(window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove', 'pointermove'];
```

But that didn't seem to work, as every mouse event is still fired when i run chrome dev tools performace analysis.

[Screenshot of the performance test, showing multiple events fired where i only waved the pointer around the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivBdk.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i'm currently running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i dug a little deeper and eventually came across [this link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517069/black-the-zonejs-listening-event-list-in-polyfills-ts-in-angular-8-not-working)

Apparently, you need to create a new file with the above flag and import it into polyfills before you import zone.js. Hope this helps someone else.