# How to call HttpClient outside Angular Zone?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, zone

In my app, I need to call a slow API endpoint on page loading.
This call doesn't really affect the app but should be performed right on page load.

During the whole time the request is performed, there's a macro-task in the queue which prevents Angular Zone from becoming stable and non-testable (in e2e-tests).

This is the only thing I need to be ignored by Zone, all other ones should be waited as usual and many tests already depend on it.
So turning `waitForAngularEnabled` off in the tests is not the best option.

I tried to perform this long-lasting call outside Angular Zone like this:

```js
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.httpClient.post(...))
```

The `XMLHttpRequest` task is still in the queue and blocks Zone stability:
[image: Zone Task]

Please advise what's the way to run Http requests outside Angular Zone?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the configuration that I am using to completely ignore XHR from zone:

```
(window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = [
  // mouse and pointer events - the presence of these here can break angular material tooltips
  'mouseover', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'scroll', 'mousewheel', 'pointerover',
  // XHR related events
  'load', 'mouseleave', 'readystatechange', 'loadend', 'loadstart', 'progress'];

(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
(window as any).__Zone_disable_IE_check = true;
(window as any).__Zone_disable_XHR = true;


// The creator of Zone also suggest ignoring properties directly on XHR
// https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1146
(window as any).__Zone_ignore_on_properties = [
  {
    target: XMLHttpRequest.prototype,
    ignoreProperties: ['load', 'readystatechange', 'loadstart', 'loadend', 'progress']
  }
];
```

Also make sure that this is not directly inside polyfills.ts but rather in a file that is included ([Black the zonejs "listening" event list in polyfills.ts in Angular 8 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517069/black-the-zonejs-listening-event-list-in-polyfills-ts-in-angular-8-not-working))

I have based this on the discussion inside this issue:
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1146